# rsync not using --files-from option?

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to run `rsync -a --files-from=~/.rsync_file_list ~/destination` and it tells me: `rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at options.c(1652) [client=3.0.7]`. Can anyone enlighten me as to what I'm doing wrong?

The file `~/.rsync_file_list` just contains a list of file names prefaced with `~/`, separated by newlines (though I've also tried listing them all on the same line, with the same result).

If I run `rsync -a ~/file ~/file2 ~/file3 ~/destination` it works just fine. So what am I missing about the `--files-from` option?

Comment: try `sed "s#~/#/home/wolf/#g" -ie ~/.rsync_file_list`

Comment: @Andy: Alas, same result.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem.

1. The file containing file names has to contain *only* file names; no paths, relative or otherwise;
2. After specifying `--files-from=FILE`, rsync requires a source directory in which to find the files listed.

So the command should be `rsync -a --files-from=~/.rsync_file_list $HOME/ /destination`.

`.rsync_file_list` should read:

```
file 1
file 2
file 3
```

Comment: Correction: File names in the given file ARE relative to the source directory, but cannot be above it (no `../`). Leading slashes will be ignored, so absolute paths don't work.

Comment: I believe you can edit your own answer and add this very nice addition and relevant piece of info you found out later in the answer itself.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the source folder, I thought it was implicitly the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "~" may not work inside a "files-from" file unless rsync is smart enough to recognize and translate the "~" symbol.

When you specify a "~" as part of a command in your shell's command line, it is the *shell* itself that converts "~" to your home directory *before* passing the argument along to the program.  So even though you type `rsync -a ~/file`, what `rsync` "sees" is actually the resolved path, or `rsync -a /home/foo/file`.

See [Bash Tilde Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) for more information.